# How can I get my PS3 to recognize my Pi as a Media Server?

Tags: networking

We recently ordered a new computer, it had Windows 8 installed, and one of the things we noticed was that our PS3 saw the new computer, and could access its shared files. I tried to replicate this with sambashare, but the PS3 never noticed the Pi, even after adding it to the same workgroup as the new computer.

What's the problem? Is the PS3 picking up something other than the Windows Share? Something secret and proprietary perhaps?

(Please add tags [samba](/questions/tagged/samba), [share](/questions/tagged/share), or any other relevant tags to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Windows Share/Samba, but DLNA that your PS3 is seeing. I had to turn on DLNA via Media Player on my Windows XP and Windows 7 machine, but my PS3/Android devices see all my DLNA servers, including my Pi.

Here is a step-by-step: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=16352

Comment: Score! It worked! Bonus round: how do I change its icon? Right now, it's the Debian logo; I'd like it to be [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Raspberry_Pi_Logo.svg).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a convenient way to change the logo but it is possible if you compile the server from source.

Create a directory to store your logo and in order to complete what you are asking you need your logo saved in two different sizes and two different formats:
Large = 102px Height x 120px Width
Small = 48px Height x 41px Width
and you need them saved in both PNG and jpg.
Name your image outputs like:
png_sm.png
png_lrg.png
jpeg_sm.jpg
jpeg_lrg.jpg

There is a great piece of code on sourceforge that does all the hard work and formatting for you.
[sourceforge-code-snippet](https://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/discussion/879956/thread/cc0ccac8/)
Create a empty file conversion.c and this content:

```
/* convert icon data for icons.c" */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, c;
    FILE *rfp, *wfp;
    if (argc < 3) {fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s inputfilename outputfilename\n\n", argv[0]); exit(1);}
    rfp = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    if (rfp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "cannot open \"%s\"\n", argv[1]); exit(1);}
    wfp = fopen (argv[2], "wb");
    if (wfp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "cannot create  \"%s\"e\n", argv[2]); exit(1);}
    for (; ;) {
        fprintf(wfp, "             \"");
        for (i=0; i<24 ; i++) {
            c = fgetc(rfp); if (c == EOF) break;
            c = fprintf(wfp, "\\x%02x", c); if (c<0) goto end;
        }
        fprintf(wfp, "\"\n");
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }
end:
    fclose(rfp);
    fclose(wfp);
    exit(0);
}
```

now compile it:
`gcc conversion.c`

Instead of doing all files individually use a bit of bash, convert.sh:

```
./a.out jpeg_lrg.jpg jpeg_lrg.jpg.hex
./a.out jpeg_sm.jpg jpeg_sm.jpg.hex
./a.out png_lrg.png png_lrg.png.hex
./a.out png_sm.png png_sm.png.hex
```

Make it executable `chmod +x convert.sh` and run it `./convert.sh`
You will see copies of your logo with a .hex just copy and paste the their content into the appropriate places of the icons.c file located in the root directory of miniDLNA source folder.

Build and run :)
I have found that the dependencies needed to build miniDLNA successfully are:

```
sudo apt install autoconf g++ subversion linux-source linux-headers-`uname -r` build-essential tofrodos git-core subversion dos2unix make gcc automake cmake checkinstall git-core dpkg-dev fakeroot pbuilder dh-make debhelper devscripts patchutils quilt git-buildpackage pristine-tar git yasm checkinstall cvs mercurial autopoint debhelper dh-autoreconf gcc libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg-dev libsqlite3-dev libexif-dev libid3tag0-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libflac-dev
```

NOTE: If someone knows a more trimmed down depends list please post here.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This seems interesting, but the question didn't mention anything about changing a logo.

Comment: I didn't have enough "reputation" to comment on:
"Score! It worked! Bonus round: how do I change its icon? Right now, it's the Debian logo; I'd like it to be this image. – JamesTheAwesomeDude May 30 '13 at 17:24"

Comment: The OP should not have placed a new question in a comment. You could create a new question yourself, and post this answer to that question.